# Should I try to migrate to a new server myself?

Tags: migration, linux

We have a Linux server running a PHP/MySQL CMS (that I wrote).  We have about 50,000 users and it's time to upgrade to a new server with more resources. Our server company (ServerBeach) says we can just click on a link they provide: Migrate.  And voila!

But I suspect it isn't that easy.  I'm a programmer; not a server expert at all. I have no clue what to do if something goes wrong.

Should I trust ServerBeach to just click on the link and pray that it all works?  (They are an outfit that provides hardware; we have a third-party company that provides server support, but they won't do a migration.)

I feel like I'm in over my head here; any suggestions?

Are there any outfits that provide this kind of service -- or that we can switch to, from our present 3rd party company?

Thanks

...Vidya
www.opednews.com
vidya@webwisesage.com

Comment: A third party company that provides server support but won't do a migration? I suggest you find someone else to provide your support, as this suggests to me they don't really have the expertise.

Answer (score 2):

It depends, but basically, if they offer the service, is because they can.

If this is a VPS, the upgrade is basically shutting down the VM, bumping up the VM configuration (adding more RAM), and perhaps moving the VM to another physical box.

If this is a dedicated box, this is slightly more complicated, but it can be done.

Managed hosting is probably even simpler than VPS.

Answer (score 0):

Well, how much do you trust your provider? I've never worked with ServerBeach, but I do know they've been around for a while. If customers had frequent issues with ServerBeach's migration method, I'd bet you'd be able to find it pretty readily with a bit of Google searching. I've done several of this type of migration with Linode, and they've all been 100% seamless. I'd guess you'd be just fine taking advantage of their 1-click migration.

Regardless of whether SB ends up doing the migration or some other party, you ought to make sure to do a *very thorough* backup of everything beforehand.